# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error - 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<''. I do not know why I am getting this error. I've tried different things but still not working. Can anyone please help me with this. Please find below my demo code-

index.html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root" >Loading...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app/app'

 ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>I am root Component</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Package.json-

```
"dependencies": {
    "es6-object-assign": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Pleae could you provide your configuration details? Which tools are you using? CRA? Pure webpack? Seems like your code is not git transpiled well.

Comment: I've updated the main question. It's using the react-scripts. Apart from this not using any specific tool.

Comment: What file and line number are the errors reported on? How are you launching the app? If you're using the dev server, have you confirmed that the URL in the browser's address bar points to it?

Comment: Yup I am using the development server, I've used the same URL provided by react-scripts. My URL is pointing at the right path. Moreover, it's showing only the 'Loading...'. It's showing error in the first line of index.html in developer tools all the time.